# How to determine if SocketIO is using SSL/Encryption?

Tags: sockets, ssl, https, wss, socket.io

**PROBLEM:** Before I start sending OAuth tokens back and forth, I want to test that my sockets are communicating over an encrypted SSL connection.

**My Setup:** Since my hosting is done on Modulus, I have selected "Auto-SSL Redirect" (all requests using non-SSL routes will automatically be 302 redirected to the https).

I assume (but want to test) that this means that I don't have to set SSL up in node, so I have set up my server like so:

```
//Note: This is only a portion of my code, let me know if more is needed
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(port, function() {});
```

Client side HTML:

```
var JsonRes = { query: 'token=a&type=a', secure: true};
socket = io.connect('https://my-project-101.onmodulus.net', JsonRes);
```

I checked the resulting handshakeData and:

1. handshakeData.secure == undefined
2. handshakeData.query == {"token":"a","type":"a","t":"1394861322578"}

Anyone know how to test that my sockets are sending/receiving encrypted data to the server?